# Change timeout value with StartService method

Tags: c++, service

I'm trying to start a service with [StartService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-startservicea) method. According to the documentation:

> StartService will block for 30 seconds if any service is busy handling a control code.

How can I change this timeout value?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You cannot change the timeout. It is builtin to the SCM, and contractually obligated by the documentation to be 30 seconds only.</strike>

**UPDATE**: Apparently, you can change the timeout after all. But only in the Registry, not in code. And it requires a reboot to take effect. See [How do I increase windows service startup timeout](https://serverfault.com/questions/622432/) on Server Fault.

It is the responsibility of each service to respond to the SCM in a timely manner. During a start request, a service needs to call `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()` as soon as possible. If it needs a lengthy startup, it should be starting the dispatcher quickly, then entering a PENDING state and report updated status at regular intervals until ready.